# mod_rewrite directory but exclude subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect

/latoya to /global-css

however i want to prevent /latoya/signup/ajax/* OR */ajax from being redirected.

I'ave tried a few ways.. but none of them are successful

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Good SO user always share what he tried first, So Please share your .htaccess file contents..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `RedirectMatch` rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/latoya/?$ /global-css
```